# How to dense and reshape a [3751,4] dataset to [1,6] dataset during training in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I am training a model that the feature shape is [3751,4] and I'd like to use reshape and layer dense function built in Tensorflow to make the output labels have the shape [1,6].

Now I am having two hidden layers in my model that will do something like:

```
input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"], [-1,11,11,31,4])
first_hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(input_layer, 4, activation=tf.nn.relu)
second_hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(first_hidden_layer, 5, activation=tf.nn.relu)
output_layer = tf.layers.dense(second_hidden_layer, 6)
```

So now I can have the output_layer shape of [?,11,11,31,6].

**How do I further shape the training node sets so it can eventually connect the nodes to the shape [1,6]?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shape `[3751, 4]` cannot be reshaped to `[-1,11,11,31,4]` directly since `3751*4 = 15004` is not evenly divisible by `11*11*31*4 = 14964`.

---

**EDIT after comment from OP**

You can flatten your dataset and feed it as a single example. See below

Assuming that `tf.shape(input_feat)==[3751, 4]`:

```
input_layer = tf.reshape(input_feat, [1,-1])
first_hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(input_layer, 4, activation=tf.nn.relu)
second_hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(first_hidden_layer, 5, activation=tf.nn.relu)
output_layer = tf.layers.dense(second_hidden_layer, 6)
```

---

**Original answer**

Not reshaping the input features at the beginning of the network will work just fine and provide similar results since you are using dense layers. The only difference is that weights in the layer will shift positions but this will not affect your results.

If we assume `tf.shape(input_feat) == [3751, 4]`, the following code snippet should work fine

```
input_layer = tf.identity(input_feat)
first_hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(input_layer, 4, activation=tf.nn.relu)
second_hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(first_hidden_layer, 5, activation=tf.nn.relu)
output_layer = tf.layers.dense(second_hidden_layer, 6)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. 3751*4 = 15004 though. Also the snippet you provided would eventually give the shape [3751,6] while I actually want [1,6].

Comment: I see. So the entire dataset should be considered as a single input example: you can do so by reshaping by to `[1, -1]` (see edit).